# How do I achieve an embroidered look on my model?

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to create plush toys in blender for a short that features a claw machine. However, I don't want to use glass eyes (which would be easier, I know). I'd prefer to use embroidered eyes, but I don't know how to achieve this look. Something like this: [image] I have a model that has a cotton texture applied to it, but I don't know how to create an eye like this and have it overlay the cotton texture. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://youtu.be/Ebx2qbBlvh0

Comment: will you need to make close-up shots? In that case you'll probably need to use hair, otherwise you can fake the cotton with texture pictures

Comment: Alright thank ya both!